# Devise: Require admin to activate account before sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to follow this wiki to have the admin approve requests for registration.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in

When I try to complete the sign up form, I get this error when I press the sign up button:

```
NameError at /users
uninitialized constant User::AdminMailer
```

It refers to line 96 in my user model. That is where this method is:

```
   def send_admin_mail
     AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver
   end
```

I have a after action for send_admin_email.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "hello@cr.com"

def send_admin_mail

mail(to: hello@cr.com, subject: 'Registration Request')
end
end
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you create a mailer called AdminMailer?

Comment: Hi David, yes. apologies. I edited my post to include it.

Comment: Can you post the entire AdminMailer class? It looks like it might be named incorrectly.

Comment: Updated to include the whole action mailer class. Thanks David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class is called UserMailer, but you're creating an instance of AdminMailer. Maybe try renaming one or the other. The tutorial suggests the class should be called AdminMailer.

Comment: Thank you Ian. I didn't realise the disconnect between the devise tutorial asking to set up a mailer and the Rails tutorial showing how to create mailers. I changed both the view and mailer names to adminmailer and got past that error. However, I have a new error with the method. I'll create another post to seek help with that. I can't see what I've done wrong. Thank you for your help with this step.